# Good way to "append" integers in C#?

Tags: c#, integer

I have two integers, ex. 15 and 6 and I want to get 156.
What I do:

```
int i = 15;
int j = 6;
Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString() + j.ToString());
```

Any better way of doing this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all of your nice answers. I run a quick Stopwatch test to see what are the performance implications:
This is a code tested on my machine:

```
static void Main()
    {
        const int LOOP = 10000000;
        int a = 16;
        int b = 5;
        int result = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
        {
            result = AppendIntegers3(a, b);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}ms, LastResult({1})", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,result);
    }
```

And here's the timing:

```
My original attempt: ~3700ms 
Guffa 1st answer: ~105ms 
Guffa 2nd answer: ~110ms 
Pent Ploompuu answer: ~990ms 
shenhengbin answer: ~3830ms 
dasblinkenlight answer: ~3800ms
Chris Gessler answer: ~105ms
```

Guffa provided a very nice and smart solution and Chris Gessler provided a very nice extension method for that solution.

Comment: Why would you need a better way if that way works and is fast?

Comment: toString() is not needed as there is a concatenation

Comment: I was thinking there's a built-in way of doing it with int datatype like shifting or something similar

Comment: @Shyju, If I'm not adding .ToString() then my result is 21 not 156

Comment: @user194076 Shifting would help if the numbers were binary, octal, or hex.

Comment: Guys, who is voting this down? Its a valid question, even if his desire is strange. He has a solution, and wants to know if a better one exists. Don't downvote for that.

Comment: @user194076: Yes, you can do shifting, but as you want decimal numbers you shift by multiplying by 10.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it numerically. No string conversion needed:

```
int i=15;
int j=6;

int c = 1;
while (c <= j) {
  i *= 10;
  c *= 10;
}
int result = i + j;
```

or:

```
int c = 1;
while (c <= j) c *= 10;
int result = i * c + j;
```

Comment: Unless there was a particular reason -- which there may be -- for "needing faster", I would just use a variation of the string concat .. but +1 for a different approach.

Comment: +1 i wonder if it's faster than @dasblinkenlight's `string` approach? anyone care to post test result FSAG (for shit's and giggles)...

Comment: @Xander It avoids much of the same math (and extra overhead and intermediate strings) wrapped in the BCL for the conversion steps; I would expect it to win a micro any-day. Of course, a micro is a micro.. and I would accept this code *only* behind an apt-named function (or very particular benchmarked performance case).

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this code *can* silently overflow. May or may not matter.

Comment: @pst: Good point. You could use the second version and check if `i > Int32.MaxValue/c` to catch an overflow.

Comment: I've added some performance testing in case anyone is interested. And Thank you guffa for your cool answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Append(this int n, int i)
    {
        int c = 1;
        while (c <= i) c *= 10;
        return n * c + i; 
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
    int x = 123;
    int y = x.Append(4).Append(5).Append(6).Append(789);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: If you're using the more number-based approach, it'll be faster (and purer) to use `(int)Math.Log10(i) + 1` instead of `i.ToString().Length` (as seen in Pent Ploompuu's answer)...

Comment: Wow, when I see multiplication by ten coded as `((p << 2) + p) << 1`, I can tell that the author has considerable experience programming in assembly language :) I stopped using this trick about two decades ago, after seeing an optimizing C compiler for an 8-bit CPU compile multiplication by constant into a series of shifts and additions.

Comment: I tested using shifts and adds instead of multiplication. In 64-bit mode there is no performance difference. In 32-bit mode it's actually *slower* than a multiplication...

Comment: @Guffa - Thanks for the performance review, but the point of my solution is to turn whatever solution into an Extension to achieve method chaining.  I updated my answer again, but really, a few nanoseconds will not make much of a difference here.  If I needed to append 10 billion integers, that would be a different story.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: I just pointed that out because the code was obviously written to try to be faster. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int res = j == 0 ? i : i * (int)Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Log10(j) + 1) + j;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use `string.Concat(i,j)`

Answer (score -2):

```
int i=15
int j=6
int result=i*10+6;
```

Comment: This answer assumes the j variable is less than 10.